# How to find if a phone is in sleep mode or not???

Tags: android, sleep, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I want my application to run all time. It should execute a function when phone is in sleep mode and stop the execution when it is asleep. Can anyone post a sample code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sleep == asleep, can you clarify?

Comment: I want to be notified when the screensaver comes(sleep)

Comment: @Mac: "i want my application to be running at all times" -- why? Users really do not like this, unless your "application" will be delivering value "at all times".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to look into WakeLocks
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html